# How can i set cell fontHeight 9 and Bold concurrently in poi apache java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using poi apache libraru to create file excell. In header column, i want to set font height is 9 and set font Bold. but i can set only one thing in two thing above. this my code. can you help me. Thank

```
    XSSFCellStyle cellFont_9 = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellFont_9.setFont(font_9);

    XSSFCellStyle cellFontBold = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellFontBold.setFont(fontBold);

    setRowStyleExcell(workbook, headerRow, cellFont_9);
    setRowStyleExcell(workbook, headerRow, cellFontBold);
```

in this case, my font is Bold

other case:

```
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFont(font_9);
    cellStyle.setFont(fontBold);
    setRowStyleExcell(workbook, headerRow, cellStyle);
```

it only Bold

this is my setRowStyleExcell() function:

```
public void setRowStyleExcell(Workbook workbook, Row row, XSSFCellStyle style){
    for(int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++){
        //For each cell in the row
        if(row.getCell(i) != null){
            row.getCell(i).setCellStyle(style);//Set the style
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You apply 2 different `CellStyles` as of now. Merge them into 1 and you are good to go

Comment: yes. i'm try to merge two font Bold and font 9 into one font and did it. thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the `Font` object with both the attributes and then set `Font` on `XSSFCellStyle`

In your case

```
Font font = .... // Initialize it the way you do now
font.setBold(true); // Set bold
font.setFontHeight((short) 9); // Set font height
cellFont_9.setFont(font_9); // Set on XSSFCellStyle
```